# How to prove this statement about Sub-sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that if the sub-series of the even numbers (the elements which has an even index) has a limit and the sub-series of the odd numbers (the elements which has an odd index) have the same limit then the whole series has the same limit both of them has.I tried to use the definition of the limit but it didnt work out.

Comment: hint: use epsilon delta definition once for evens and one for odds. Then take new epsilon equal to max of epsilons for odds and evens.

Comment: Never heard of epsilon delta can you explain please?

Comment: You can look at wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit its pretty well expained

Comment: Im talking about a sequence not function therefore I dont need to use delta

Comment: So it would be $\varepsilon$-$N$, i.e. $x_n\to x$ iff for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $d(x_n,x)<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ be the real numbers that work for $s_{2n} \to s$ and $s_{2n+1} \to s$.

Hint: Let $\epsilon = \max \left(\epsilon_1, \, \epsilon_2 \right)$. Then, for any $n, \, \left| s_n - s \right|$ ...

Edit: Here is a proof.

Let $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ be the real numbers that work for $s_{2n} \to s$ and $s_{2n+1} \to s$. Then, there exists $N_1$ and $N_2$ so that

$$\left| s_{2n} - s \right| < \epsilon_1$$

when $2n > N_1$, and similarly,

$$\left| s_{2n+1} - s \right| < \epsilon_2$$

when $2n+1 > N_2$.

Let $N=N_1+N_2$, and fix $\epsilon = \max \left(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \right)$. Now, show that this $\epsilon$ works for our choice of $N$ based on what we have realized above. I will leave this to you.

Comment: I couldnt understand how to use the epsilon role here?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you don't understand. Do you know what the rigorous definition of $s_n \to s$ is?

Comment: It means that s is the limit of Sn but I dont understand how picking a maximum value of epsilon can help you prove this statement

Comment: No, what is the *rigorous* definition of $s_n \to s$. "$s$ is the limit of $s_n$" is not the definition we are looking for.

Comment: I didnt understand your comment

Comment: Please look at my edited answer.

Comment: So,from the last line the conclusion is:- Let epsilon be the max of both epsilons.There is an N=N1+N2 which implies that for n>N the limit of sn is s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23094/discussion-between-shadi-helf-and-mathmajor).